# show paired bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an app that shows available paired devices.

It works the first time, shows the one paired device in range, but if I close and reopen the app the device doesn't show. Both BTs are on, and they are paired

Any ideas as to why?

**Code**

```
private void getPairedDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size() > 0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Thats my code for getting the paired devices and adding them to the array.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    if(btAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no bluetooth detectd", 0).show();
        finish();
    }
    else{
        if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
            turnOnBt();
        }   
    }
    getPairedDevices();
    startDiscovery();
}
private void startDiscovery() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
private void turnOnBt() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    btAdapter.enable();
}
private void getPairedDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size() > 0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

where the method fits in and is called from.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call that method from?

Comment: @tolgap I've thrown in the code where it is called from, along with everything else.